# SD card is read-only, all Disk Utility options grayed out

Tags: macos, disk-utility, sd-card

I'm using Lion (10.7.3) on a mid-2010 MacBook Pro. I just got a 32GB SD card and formatted it with my camera. I'd like to transfer some files onto it from my computer, but the card seems to be read-only when I access it in Finder. And in Disk Utility, all options are grayed out so I can't reformat the card.

[image]

[image]

I found [this KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2176) which seems to describe the problem, but the solution doesn't work:

```
$ diskutil partitiondisk disk1 JHFS+ newdisk 100%
Started partitioning on disk1
Unmounting disk
Error: -69877: Couldn't open device
```

What's going on and how can I get around it?

**Edit:** yes, I already checked the physical lock switch on the card!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not sure what the problem was — after some more formatting and fiddling around, the issue resolved itself.

Answer (score 2):

I was just going to suggest the lock switch too... but if that's not it, can you click the Partition tab and tell us how the card is currently formatted?  If I remember right, OS X can read but not write an NTFS-formatted device, but it seems unlikely that your camera would have formatted the card that way.

Comment: It's shown as "MS-DOS (FAT)" as in the first screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the exact same thing... the issue was that the lock switch was getting flipped when I pushed the card into the slot and it would flip back to unlock when I pulled the card out, lol.  I was able to get it in without the switch flipping by pushing it to the opposite side of where the switch is.

Answer (score 1):

The only other time I've seen this is when the card was locked. Did you accidentally hit the lock mechanism on the corner of the card?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I already checked this. Thanks though.